# How to docstring a function arugument which is itself a function with arguments in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How can I docstring an argument which is a function itself?

Example:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param secondFunction // I want to say this should be a function that accepts a number
 */
function firstFunction(secondFunction) {
    const a = 1;
    secondFunction(a);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: What annotation are you using? JSDoc? ESDoc? If it's JSDoc, take a look at their documentation https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#callback-functions

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am using JSDoc, and I found it in the link you provided! I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks for your help. If you post an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#callback-functions):

#### Callback functions

If a parameter accepts a callback function, you can use the [`@callback` tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-callback.html) to define a callback type, then include the callback type in the `@param` tag.

**Parameters that accept a callback**

```
/**
 * This callback type is called `secondFunction` and is displayed as a global symbol.
 *
 * @callback secondFunction
 * @param {number} a
 */

/**
 * executes secondFunction
 * @param {secondFunction} secondFunction - The callback
 */
function firstFunction(secondFunction) {
    const a = 1;
    secondFunction(a);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define the type of the parameter to be the function signature you expect to be passed:

```
/** Calls second function with 1
 * @param {(a:number)=>void} secondFunction
 */
function firstFunction(secondFunction) {
    const a = 1;
    secondFunction(a);
};
```

Comment: This is also really good!